# react-final-form handle when field change after change in another field and why formspy runs 2 times?

Tags: react-final-form

I'm working with react-final-form and I want to handle two events:

1. when one field (i.e. "age") was changed because another field (i.e. "date of birth") was changed and age was in validateFields

```
<Field
    name='birthdate'
    ...
    validateFields={['age']}
/>
```

2. I'm trying to handle when form **was not** submitted successfully

```
<form>
    <Field
        name='birthdate'
        ...
        validateFields={['age']}
    />
    <FormSpy
        onChange={(props) => {
            console.log('props.submitFailed triggers 2 times', props.submitFailed);
        }}
    />
</form>
```

My formspy onchange runs 2 times. Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Answer on first question is that "age" changes not because it listed in validateFields, but because it listed in special function of decorator final-form-calculate, which has function, where I can handle it's change.

2/ Probably it happens because I didn't listed subscription option in subscription of formspy and it runs each subscription option (in my case 2 or 3 of them)